# How to access shared field in structs in generics in Go 1.18? I get error "type t has no field or method DATE_START"

Tags: go, generics

I have two structs that have the some of the same field names and types:

```
type JOURNAL_TAG struct {
    DATE_START            time.Time
    DATE_END              time.Time
    ENTRY_NUMBER          uint
    VALUE                 float64
}

type INVENTORY_TAG struct {
    DATE_START   time.Time
    DATE_END     time.Time
    PRICE        float64
    QUANTITY     float64
    ACCOUNT_NAME string
}
```

and I have a func that accesses the common field `DATE_START` that should sort the slices of these types:

```
func sort_by_time[t JOURNAL_TAG|INVENTORY_TAG](slice []t, is_ascending bool) {
    sort.Slice(slice, func(i, j int) bool {
        return slice[i].DATE_START.After(slice[j].DATE_START) == is_ascending
    })
}
```

Running `go build` reports a compiler error:

```
slice[i].DATE_START undefined (type t has no field or method DATE_START)
```

I want to sort the slices of these two types using generics, is it possible?

I am using go 1.18.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Go 1.18 release notes](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.18#generics):

> The Go compiler does not support accessing a struct field x.f where x is of type parameter type even if all types in the type parameter's type set have a field f. We may remove this restriction in Go 1.19.

You could for example add a `DateStart() time.Time` method to each of the structs that returns the DATE_START field, and then use that method as part of your [type constraint](https://go.dev/doc/tutorial/generics#declare_type_constraint) if you wanted to use generics.

That said, you don't need generics for this specific problem. Even without generics, you could define an interface:

```
type SomeInterface interface {
    DateStart() time.Time
}
```

and then sort:

```
items := []SomeInterface{
    INVENTORY_TAG{...},
    INVENTORY_TAG{...},
}
sort.Slice(items, func(i, j int) bool { return items[i].DateStart().Before(items[j].DateStart()) })
```

Answer (score 5):

Like @thepudds says in this case is better use a interface implementation, but if you want try generics you could do:

```
package main

type JOURNAL_TAG struct {
    DATE_START            time.Time
    DATE_END              time.Time
    ENTRY_NUMBER          uint
    VALUE                 float64
}

type INVENTORY_TAG struct {
    DATE_START   time.Time
    DATE_END     time.Time
    PRICE        float64
    QUANTITY     float64
    ACCOUNT_NAME string
}

type hasDateInterface interface {
    DateStart() time.Time
}

func (j JOURNAL_TAG) DateStart(){
   return j.DATE_START
}

func (i INVENTORY_TAG) DateStart(){
   return i.DATE_START
}

func sort_by_time[t hasDateInterface](slice []t, is_ascending bool) {
    sort.Slice(slice, func(i, j int) bool {
        return slice[i].DATE_START.After(slice[j].DateStart()) == is_ascending
    })
}
```

tried
https://go.dev/play/p/Xak4uzCNhE-

Comment: I think the first DATE_START in sort_by_time needs to be DateStart(), no?