# Using generic function to reset cache

Tags: go, generics

I'm just now starting to work with generics for a project. I've set up the following example in a go playground. I'm trying to create a generic function to reset the cache of 2 different types, that have the same fields. Furthermore, I can't figure out why I can't access those fields withing the generic function.

The error is:

```
./prog.go:21:4: c.Count undefined (type *C is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter)
./prog.go:22:4: c.List undefined (type *C is pointer to type parameter, not type parameter)
```

Any help is appreciated.

https://go.dev/play/p/ojkNe1D-hSE

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type CacheOne struct {
    Count int
    List  []string
}

type CacheTwo struct {
    Count int
    List  []string
}

type cachable interface {
    CacheOne | CacheTwo
}

// resetSCache resets the Count & List of a given cachable type.
func resetCache[C cachable](c *C) {
    c.Count = 0
    c.List = []string{}
}

func main() {
    // Example usage
    dOne := &CacheOne{
        Count: 5,
        List:  []string{"hello", "world"},
    }
    dTwo := &CacheTwo{
        Count: 5,
        List:  []string{"hello", "world"},
    }

    fmt.Println("Before reseting...whould be populated with data")
    fmt.Println(dOne)
    fmt.Println(dTwo)

    resetCache(dOne)
    resetCache(dTwo)

    fmt.Println("Before reseting...whould be reset with zero values")
    fmt.Println(dOne)
    fmt.Println(dTwo)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're trying to achieve is not permitted by Go as of now. You can find more details in this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71531151/14394371). Probably something could change in the future but AFAIK, you've to stick to the following implementation:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type CacheOne struct {
    Count int
    List  []string
}

type CacheTwo struct {
    Count int
    List  []string
}

type cachable interface {
    SetCount(count int)
    SetList([]string)
}

func (c *CacheOne) SetCount(count int) {
    c.Count = count
}

func (c *CacheOne) SetList(list []string) {
    c.List = list
}

func (c *CacheTwo) SetCount(count int) {
    c.Count = count
}

func (c *CacheTwo) SetList(list []string) {
    c.List = list
}

// resetSCache resets the Count & List of a given cachable type.
func resetCache[C cachable](c C) {
    c.SetCount(0)
    c.SetList(make([]string, 0))
}

func main() {
    // Example usage
    dOne := &CacheOne{
        Count: 5,
        List:  []string{"hello", "world"},
    }
    dTwo := &CacheTwo{
        Count: 5,
        List:  []string{"hello", "world"},
    }

    fmt.Println("Before reseting...whould be populated with data")
    fmt.Println(dOne)
    fmt.Println(dTwo)

    resetCache(dOne)
    resetCache(dTwo)

    fmt.Println("Before reseting...whould be reset with zero values")
    fmt.Println(dOne)
    fmt.Println(dTwo)
}
```

If you run this code, you should get the desired output:

```
Before reseting...whould be populated with data
&{5 [hello world]}
&{5 [hello world]}
Before reseting...whould be reset with zero values
&{0 []}
&{0 []}
```

I agree that this method could be a little cumbersome but it's what is :)
If you find a smarter way to achieve just let me know in case.
I hope that this helps you in solving your issue, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the details. That was kinda the conclusion that I came to, but was hopping I was wrong!